# I can't get this right in Python?

Tags: python

I was studying Python on this website www.codacademy.com and I'm stuck on exercise PygLatin in part 4 of 12.

"Write an if statement that checks to see if the string is not empty.

If the string is not empty, print the user's word.
Otherwise (else), print "empty" if the string is empty.
Make sure you thoroughly test your code. You'll want to make sure you run it multiple times and test both an empty string and a string with characters. When you are confident that your code works, continue on to the next exercise."

I have to print the user's input word if he does so, if not, print "empty".

```
original = raw_input("Welcome to the English to Pig Latin translator! Type in the word you wish to use.")

    if len(original) > 0:
        return raw_input
    else:
        return "empty"

print original
```

But it's not working, I need help.
What am I doing wrong? The error claims it's on line 2 (if len(original) > 0:) but I haven't figured out what's wrong.

Comment: Can you share the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two main problems: indentation and return without a function.

If you want to use a function, you could define a function that receive a string parameter, checks if it's empty, and then returns the corresponding string.

For example:

```
def checkstring(string):
    if len(string) > 0:
        return string
    else:
        return "empty"

original = "Welcome to the English to Pig Latin translator! Type in the word you wish to use."
print checkstring(original)
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrong indentation is the main problem. Also, you have `return` statements but don't have a function. Plus, you can simplify the check if `original` is empty:

```
original = raw_input("Welcome to the English to Pig Latin translator! Type in the word you wish to use.")

if original:
    print original
else:
    print "empty"
```

or, in one line:

```
print original if original else "empty"
```

or:

```
print original or "empty"
```

Comment: Bah. `print original or "empty"`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker this is more pythonic, thanks, included in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't indent arbitrarily in Python. The four lines beginning with the `if` statement are indented one level further than the first statement: that's not allowed. You can only indent after a statement that introduces a new block, as you have done after `if` and `else`. Bring those four lines back a level so that they start at the left-hand side.

Answer (score 0):

I got the code from "Quine"but I edited more so you can actually put the input. Works better if you ask me for the purpose of this exercise:

```
print "Welcome to the English to Pig Latin translator!"
def checkstring(original):
    if len(original) > 0:
        return original
    else:
        return "empty"
original = raw_input("What is your name?")
print checkstring(original)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print 'Welcome to the Pig Latin Translator!'

# Start coding here!
raw_input ("What is your name")
variable_name = raw_input ()
original = raw_input()
if len (original) > 0:
    print "the user's word"
else:
    print "empty"
```